# How to make a <div>'s bottom edge below background image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a background image, but I need to place a div that its bottom edge should go below the image. What's the easiest way to do this?

Please see the attached image. The white part is the background image and the blue part is my div over the background.

[image: Layout]

Comment: provide your html and css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've created a container with a background image and placed a div inside.

I've given the `.block` `margin: auto;` to center it and added `position: relative;` so I can move it, because it has `position: relative;` I can add `top: 100px;` to move it down from the top by `100px`

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  width: 100%;
  background-position: cover;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .block {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Extra info by @I_Can_Help

In the case of using percents for `bottom` it will be related with the wrapper height, but you can use `bottom: 0;`
and `transform: translate(-50%, 15%);` in order to set the upper block vertical position as relative to the block itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a relative positioned wrapper and then set absolute positioning with `bottom: -10%;` or `bottom: -20px;` for a div over a div with image:

```css
.image-with-block-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f42a832da648291bf80206eda08e3332?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
}

.div-over-bg {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class='image-with-block-wrapper'>
  <div class='image'></div>
  <div class='div-over-bg'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
In the case of using percents for `bottom` it will be related with the wrapper height, but you can use `bottom: 0;`
and `transform: translate(-50%, 15%);` in order to set the upper block vertical position as relative to the block itself.

Comment: This is the exact same answer as mine but you use bottom instead of top AND MY PICTURE!!! XD

Comment: @Nico Shultz No, it is not exact same - I use `transform` and a div-wrapper. The code differs too in class names. Also I had not seen your answer when was writing mine. I added the picture little further and by a some strange reason confused you with the question creator) So took your picture by the mistake) Also I was going to edit my answer to add some info, but it seems that I edited your answer instead of mine .

Comment: Wauw you are on a roll! :D but yeah true your answer is a lil different than mine :)